# Can I remove the Windows10Upgrade directory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filesystems

I see after I did a recent upgrade I now have a directory called Windows10Upgrade on my C: drive.  Does anyone know if this is safe to delete?

Comment: sure, delete it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They should be safe to delete as they're only the files used to update windows.

Comment: It's safe do delete manually, but if you don't, it will go away 30 days after the upgrade.  Or at least, it's supposed to.

Answer (score 22):

To remove this folder, uninstall "Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant". ([Source.](http://www.windows10forums.com/threads/how-to-safely-remove-windows10upgrade.10161/#post-47873))

Comment: That did not remove the directory when I tested it

Comment: It removed the directory when I run it

Comment: Tested uninstall again on Windows 10 Creators Update, now it removed the directory.

Comment: That did not remove the directory it self, but all the content except a HttpHelper.exe

Comment: In my case it is called Windows 10 Up**d**ate assistant.